# WooCommerce additional fees based on purchased quantity for specific products

Tags: php, woocommerce, cart, product-quantity, fee

Here is the code I currently have:

```
add_action('woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees' , 'add_custom_fees');
function add_custom_fees( $cart ){

    if (is_admin() && !defined('DOING_AJAX')) {
        return;
    }

    $pizza_ice = 0;
    $pizza_materials = 0;
    $gravy_ice = 0;
    $gravy_materials = 0;

    $pizza_burger = 293;
    $gravy = 462;
    
    $pizza_in_cart = false;
    $gravy_in_cart = false;

    foreach( $cart->get_cart() as $item ){
        $product_in_cart = $item['product_id'];
        if ( $product_in_cart === $pizza_burger) {
            $pizza_in_cart = true;
        }
        elseif ( $product_in_cart === $gravy) {
            $gravy_in_cart = true;
        }
    }

    if ( $pizza_in_cart != false ) {
        $pizza_ice += $item['quantity'] * 27;
        $pizza_materials += $item['quantity'] * 9.99;

        $cart->add_fee( 'Dry Ice - Pizza Burger', $pizza_ice);
        $cart->add_fee( 'Shipping Materials - Pizza Burger', $pizza_materials);
    }
    elseif ( $gravy_in_cart != false ) {
        $gravy_ice += $item['quantity'] * 27;
        $gravy_materials += $item['quantity'] * 6.99;

        $cart->add_fee( 'Dry Ice - Frozen Gravy', $gravy_ice);
        $cart->add_fee( 'Shipping Materials - Frozen Gravy', $gravy_materials);
    }
    elseif ( $pizza_in_cart != false || $gravy_in_cart != false ) {
        $pizza_ice += $item['quantity'] * 27;
        $pizza_materials += $item['quantity'] * 9.99;

        $cart->add_fee( 'Dry Ice - Pizza Burger', $pizza_ice);
        $cart->add_fee( 'Shipping Materials - Pizza Burger', $pizza_materials);

        $gravy_ice += $item['quantity'] * 27;
        $gravy_materials += $item['quantity'] * 6.99;

        $cart->add_fee( 'Dry Ice - Frozen Gravy', $gravy_ice);
        $cart->add_fee( 'Shipping Materials - Frozen Gravy', $gravy_materials);
    }

}
```

What I am trying to do is:

- If Pizza Burger product is in the cart, it should add the Dry Ice fee AND Materials fee for each quantity.
- If Frozen Gravy product is in the cart, it should add the Dry Ice fee AND Materials fee for each quantity.
- If both Pizza Burger and Frozen Gravy products are in the cart, it should add BOTH Dry Ice fees AND BOTH Materials fees for each quantity.

What am I doing wrong here?

When this snippet is active, It's only working for the Gravy. Changing the quantity for Pizza Burgers has no effect on the new fees.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some mistakes in your code, try the following instead:

```
add_action('woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees' , 'add_custom_fees');
function add_custom_fees( $cart ){
    if (is_admin() && !defined('DOING_AJAX')) 
        return;

    ## -- product Ids -- ##    
    $pizza_id = 293;
    $gravy_id = 462;
    
    ## -- dry Ice & Materials fee amounts -- ##  
    $pizza_ice = $gravy_ice = 27;
    $pizza_mat = 9.99;
    $gravy_mat = 6.99;

    $gravy_qty = $pizza_qty = 0; // Initializing

    // Loop through cart items
    foreach( $cart->get_cart() as $item ){
        if ( $item['product_id'] == $pizza_id ) {
            $pizza_qty += $item['quantity'];
        } 
        elseif ( $item['product_id'] == $gravy_id ) {
            $gravy_qty += $item['quantity'];
        }
    }

    if ( $pizza_qty > 0 ) {
        $cart->add_fee( 'Dry Ice - Pizza Burger', $pizza_qty * $pizza_ice );
        $cart->add_fee( 'Shipping Materials - Pizza Burger', $pizza_qty * $pizza_mat );
    }

    if ( $gravy_qty > 0 ) {
        $cart->add_fee( 'Dry Ice - Frozen Gravy', $gravy_qty * $gravy_ice );
        $cart->add_fee( 'Shipping Materials - Frozen Gravy', $gravy_qty * $gravy_mat );
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). It should works.

Comment: That's definitely better, but something is still off. It's changing the fee amounts for both Pizza Burger and Gravy if the Gravy quantity is 2 (https://ibb.co/JC8wzTG), but if it's changed on Pizza Burger it does nothing (https://ibb.co/Vx1G2Lb). PS - Thanks for the quick response! --- Wait, I think that was just the file not updated upon save. Retrying and will update!

Comment: It's missing a ; at the end of `$pizza_ice = $gravy_ice = 27`, fixed that, but it's still giving issues. Gravy x2 and Pizza x1 (https://ibb.co/XZvcxfd) -- Gravy x1 and Pizza x2 (https://ibb.co/WK82VKh) -- looks like it's not applying to the quantities correctly?

Comment: Not sure what happened a I'm not seeing it that way in your code now but the add_fee() shipping materials for gravy was calling pizza_qty * gravy_mat - changed it to gravy_qty and it works now. Thanks again!

Comment: @Trisha Yes I have just added missing `;` in `$pizza_ice = $gravy_ice = 27`… For `'$pizza_qty * $gravy_mat'` it was already updated… Happy that it works finally.